# Electron : How to show chrome extension on Address bar?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, electron, devtools

I have added extension in my Electron App Code. But How can I check or debug my code whether my extension installed or not.

I have added Below code to add extension

```
BrowserWindow.addExtension('/home/raman/Downloads/extension/');
```

Comment: From docs: "Adds Chrome extension located at path, and returns extension's name. The method will also not return if the extension's manifest is missing or incomplete."

Comment: @pergy I have added correct path and it return my extension name also. But I want to see extension icon on address bar.

Comment: I don't know how to access data from extension. If you are interested in that, please clarify your question! ;)

Comment: Can you clarify which address bar you're referring to? From what I understand, Electron doesn't have an address bar. Are you referring to within Chrome Dev tools?

Comment: Read the manifest.json file in extension folder, "default_icon" field is the icon for the extension.